# How to log to the same file in multiple modules

Tags: python, python-2.7

My project is composed of many modules,

I declared a log file in the `main.py`

```
LOG_FILE = "log.test.txt"
```

But how to make all the modules in my project can use the `LOG_FILE`

To export all their logs to one log file.

I know I can pass the `LOG_FILE` variable when calling other modules

```
e.g. streaming_verification.run(LOG_FILE))
```

But is it a good way ?

```
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── camera_cgi.py
│   ├── camera_cgi.pyc
│   ├── camera_cgi_converter.py
│   ├── camera_cgi_converter.pyc
│   ├── codec_info_parser.drawing
│   ├── codec_info_parser.py
│   ├── codec_info_parser.pyc
│   ├── debug_streaming_cfg.txt
│   ├── excel_parser.py
│   ├── excel_parser.pyc
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── report.py
│   ├── run.sh
│   ├── simple.py
│   ├── streaming.py
│   ├── streaming.pyc
│   ├── streaming_verification.py
│   └── streaming_verification.pyc
```

Comment: You could write a logger class using the Logging module.

Comment: You don't even need a class using the logging module, just configure a `logging.handlers.FileHandler` and you're golden. Look at the [cookbook](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html)

Answer (score 1):

From python docs (http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-from-multiple-modules):

```
If your program consists of multiple modules, here’s an example of how you 
could organize logging in it:

# myapp.py
import logging
import mylib

def main():
    logging.basicConfig(filename='myapp.log', level=logging.INFO)
    logging.info('Started')
    mylib.do_something()
    logging.info('Finished')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

# mylib.py
import logging

def do_something():
    logging.info('Doing something')
```

Comment: Like Jayanth Koushik's answer, here is a small project using a wrapper of mylogging for example: https://github.com/zhaoqifa/scod